# Laravel Is it possible to pass a variable in route group?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have following routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'group1'], function () {
    Route::get('view1', ['as' => 'group1_view1', 'uses' => 'group1Controller@get_view1']);

    Route::get('view2', ['as' => 'group1_view2', 'uses' => 'group1Controller@get_view2']);
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'group2'], function () {
    Route::get('view1', ['as' => 'group2_view1', 'uses' => 'group2Controller@get_view1']);

    Route::get('view2', ['as' => 'group2_view2', 'uses' => 'group2Controller@get_view2']);
});
```

I wish to pass variables, for example, `$title = 'group-one'` to all views in `group1` and `$title = 'group-two'` to all views in `group2`. Instead of adding variable `$title` in all methods in each group controller, is it possible to pass variables groupwise in `routes`?

Answer (score 0):

NO you cannot pass variables into route groups, but if in case you need one piece of view/code in multiple views, title for example, you can use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) instead.

Comment: Variables passed that way are bonded to views rather than groups, aren't they? i.e. The view will have the same variable `$title` no matter which route group. I want the same view say `view1` has different `$title` based on the route group it's in.

Comment: well.. one alternative can be if you have url prefixes on your route groups, you can grab that using URI segments and set the variable accordingly.